# Error:Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.(on server)

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3 for my project.Now I am setting it up to the server.

The problem occured when doing so.And i am stuck at this point of error.

WHEN I run

> composer install --no-dev

command following error occurs:

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for fgrosse/phpasn1 1.5.2 -> satisfiable by fgrosse/phpasn1[1.5.2].
    - fgrosse/phpasn1 1.5.2 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for mdanter/ecc v0.4.2 -> satisfiable by mdanter/ecc[v0.4.2].
    - mdanter/ecc v0.4.2 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for pusher/pusher-php-server 2.6.3 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[2.6.3].
    - pusher/pusher-php-server 2.6.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - pusher/pusher-php-server 2.6.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - laravel-notification-channels/pusher-push-notifications 1.0.2 requires pusher/pusher-php-server 2.6.* -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[2.6.3].
    - Installation request for laravel-notification-channels/pusher-push-notifications 1.0.2 -> satisfiable by laravel-notification-channels/pusher-push-notifications[1.0.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

`

Comment: You are missing php extensions on your server, talk to your server administrator or edit your php.ini file if you know how to do it, restart the apache/nginx service (whatever you use) and it should work..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your PHP need some ext for run your packages.

You can install that with apt-get if you use Ubuntu and PHP 5 :

```
apt-get install php5-gmp 
apt-get install php5-curl
```

If you use PHP 7:

```
apt-get install php7.0-gmp 
apt-get install php-curl
```

and etc...

After that restart your web service then it will work.

Comment: thank you very much,solved my problem, I was missing apt-get install php5-gmp .!! huge thanks

Comment: I checked php 7 but not working, still getting same issue.

Comment: Getting the same errors as mention in main question.

Comment: which version of php exactly you using ? @RajeshVishwakarma

Answer (score 7):

First, check if composer is installed by doing.

```
composer -v
```

If it is installed, do the following sequence. This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring -y
sudo apt-get install php-xml -y
```

Then finally do this.

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 4):

When I went to create a laravel project, I got this problem.

After googling, I got this solution.

I followed these steps:

Step 1: sudo apt-get install -y php7.2-gd

Step 2: sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl

Step 3: sudo apt-get install php7.2-xsl

Step 4: sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring

After following these steps just restart the server again.

And then create a new laravel project by typing: "composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname" in your terminal.

Comment: it is working, i am using ubuntu 18.04 LEMP stack. well done @Fahim Sultan

Answer (score 2):

Have you read your error message?

You are missing two PHP extensions; `gmp` and `curl`.

You just need to install them, like so:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gmp
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

This should enable them as part of installing them, otherwise you will just need to enable them manually.

Make sure you restart Apache after installing them - `sudo service apache2 reload`

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue on php7.4 then please check the following extensions should be installed :

sudo apt-get install php7.4-bcmath
sudo apt-get install php7.4-common
sudo apt-get install php7.4-json
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml

Answer (score -2):

according my php version, 
check your php version using 
php -v

sudo apt-get install php7.3-dom

Comment: it seems the problems are due to some missing extensions: gmp and curl. to solve the problems either those php extensions should be installed, or run composer install --ignore-platform-reqs;

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it. Why should installing the DOM extension solve the given problem?