# Laravel: Error installing php-pusher with composer

Tags: php, laravel

I want to install pusher/pusher-php-server for my laravel app, for that I use the following command in windows:

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

Issue is I'm getting the following error and I don't know how to solve it:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for pusher/pusher-php-server ^7.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[7.0.0, 7.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.4.x-dev, 7.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.4.x-dev, 7.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.4.x-dev, 7.1.1].
    - Conclusion: install guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.4.x-dev
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 7.1.1, required as ^7.0.1) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.1.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

My composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "christiankuri/laravel-favorite": "^1.4",
        "fabpot/goutte": "^4.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel-notification-channels/fcm": "~2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^3.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: check these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790281/erroryour-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set-of-packages

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your exact issue with your exact composer.json. Try removing your `package.lock` file as well as your `vendor` directory and running that command again in case something got locked in the past but never got cleaned up correctly

Comment: @apokryfos package.lock or composer.lock?

Comment: sorry `composer.lock`